# Python ZIP Function gives unexpected output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struggling to get the `zip` function of `Python 2.7` to work to provide the output which I need.

Example of the data which I have:

```
print(score_data[0:3])
[['0/1:7,3:10:99', '0/0:3:3:99'], ['0/0:12:12:99', '0/1:11,7:18:99'], ['0/1:8,7:15:99', '0/1:14,4:18:99']]
```

The type of output which I want

```
[['0/1:7,3:10:99','0/1:8,7:15:99', '0/0:12:12:99'], [ '0/1:11,7:18:99','0/0:3:3:99', '0/1:14,4:18:99']]
```

The output which I am getting:

```
print(zip(score_data[0:3]))
[(['0/1:7,3:10:99', '0/0:3:3:99'],), (['0/0:12:12:99', '0/1:11,7:18:99'],), (['0/1:8,7:15:99', '0/1:14,4:18:99'],)]
```

Comment: `print(*score_data[0:3])` wlll give you the expected output but in a different order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wrongly applying `zip` on one list. `zip` doesn't complain, but it just adds one tuple dimension to your list, not of much use:

```
>>> list (zip([1,2,3,4]))
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
```

You need to expand the sublists as positional arguments (using `*` operator) to pass to `zip`:

```
z = [['0/1:7,3:10:99', '0/0:3:3:99'], ['0/0:12:12:99', '0/1:11,7:18:99'], ['0/1:8,7:15:99', '0/1:14,4:18:99']]

print(list(zip(*z)))   # convert to list for python 3 compat.
```

result:

```
[('0/1:7,3:10:99', '0/0:12:12:99', '0/1:8,7:15:99'), ('0/0:3:3:99', '0/1:11,7:18:99', '0/1:14,4:18:99')]
```

note that `zip` issues tuples by default. To create `list` types instead:

```
print([list(x) for x in zip(*z)])
```

result:

```
[['0/1:7,3:10:99', '0/0:12:12:99', '0/1:8,7:15:99'], ['0/0:3:3:99', '0/1:11,7:18:99', '0/1:14,4:18:99']]
```

Comment: Thank you! :-) I can accept you're answer in 11 minutes.